# How to Generate Builder in Intellij with Nested Builders like Fluent Builders Generator

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, builder

So while using eclipse, i could use the Fluent Builders Generator plugin and have the benefits of creating a nested builder classes.

For example

```
public class a {

   private String aa;
   private B b;
} 

public class b {
   private String bb;
}
```

While creating with the plugin builder class for class a, i would have the ability to use the following:

```
 ABuilder().withAA("1").withBBuilder().withBB("2").build().build();
```

Is there any plugin to inteliij that will generate these classes? the only thing i found was to create builders for both classes and use something like that:

```
 B bObject = BBuilder().withBB("1").build();
 ABuilder().withAA("1").withB(bObject).build();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Independent of the IDE, use [Immutables.github.io](https://immutables.github.io/) to generate immutable (or mutable) Value objects with [fluent builders](https://immutables.github.io/immutable.html#builder).

You just define an abstract class or interface for your value object, and the framework will generate the implementation, including the fluent builders.

And it works fine with all major IDEs.